# How to refresh access token for Google Analytics Reporting API v3

Tags: node.js, google-analytics, google-api, jwt, google-api-nodejs-client

So I am working on a Node.js app that will poll Google Analytics api ever `x` amount of seconds. I have setup a "Service Account", and converted the `p12` key to a `.pem` file. Initial setup looks something like this:

```
var authClient = new google.auth.JWT(authData.serviceEmail, authData.keyFile, null, authData.scope, '');

authClient.authorize(function(err, tokens) {
  if (err) {
    winston.log('error', 'Error authorizing with GA', {error: err});
    return;
  }

  setInterval(function() {
    analytics.data.realtime.get({
      'auth': authClient,
       ...
    }, function (err, body) {
        // getting 401 error here
    })
  }, 20000);
});
```

I had not realized that the initial tokens have an expiration date of 1 hour; however the tokens I receive look like this:

```
{
  access_token: ...,
  token_type: 'Bearer',
  expiry_date: NaN,
  refresh_token: 'jwt-placeholder
}
```

My question is, once I get that `401 invalidCredentials` error, do I simply just re-authorize to get a new access token to be able to poll from Google Analytics? I am new to JWT, and this seems like it will be authorizing way too many times. Is there a limit to this?

For reference, I am using the [Google API Node.js Client Library](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, just rebuild authClient as you did the first time. Service Accounts don't have refresh tokens like other OAuth flows, you just rebuild the authentication when the current access token expires.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! Working well now :)

Comment: do you know what the error is when the expiry date is hit for service accounts? I'm trying to fool proof the process for my app so that if the token expires, it automatically is renewed for the service account. Currently, even after the expiry hits, i dont see an error and everything is still working, which seems strange.